# Getting Attribute Error after adding html file in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a website on cPanel using django.  My models were working fine untill I created my first html page and tried to render it.  Now whenever I try to load my site I get "AttributeError at /admin/
module 'artclBlog.views' has no attribute 'home'" [pic of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXAsQ.png)

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

def home(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from artclBlog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
            ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    pageOne = models.TextField(default='')
    pageTwo = models.TextField(default='')
    pageThree = models.TextField(default='')
    pageFour = models.TextField(default='')
    date = models.DateField(default='')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Is `artclBlog` a package and views is a module? Try `from artclBlog.views import home` then `path('', home, name='home'),`

Comment: I ended up deleting " path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))," from url.py, the app worked after I did this.